MIME::QuotedPrint not encoding - what am I doing wrong?
With this code:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use strict;
use MIME::QuotedPrint;

my $encoded = "=4E=6F=74=65=73=0A=4E=6F=74=65=73=20=6C=69=6E=65=20=32";
print decode_qp($encoded);

my $decoded = "Imported today";
$encoded = encode_qp($decoded);
print "\n$encoded\n";

The first print statement gives exactly what I was expecting, but the second gives Imported today= instead of =49=6D etc.
What am I doing wrong?

The documentation of MIME::QuotedPrint says (emphasis mine):

Each non-printable character (as defined by English Americans) is represented by a triplet consisting of the character "=" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

And indeed, in the distribution's tests, you can find
    # plain ascii should not be encoded
   ["", ""],
   ["quoted printable"  =>
    "quoted printable=\n"],

So, you're not doing anything wrong, your expectation is wrong.
To get the expected output, you don't need any module:
my $encoded = join "", map sprintf("=%02X", ord), split //, 'Imported today';


That's great thanks. The format of sprintf needs to be "=%02X" to get "=0A" instead of "= a"

@SteveWaring: You're right, fixed the format :-) Thanks.
